# After posting with jQuery page is not redirecting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, post

I use jQuery to `POST` my form to controller and controller function always has at the end `return RedirectToAction("Index")` but it's not redirecting.

My jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('form').valid()) {
            var f = $("form");
            var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
                message: '<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Proszę czekać...</p>',
                size: 'small',
                closeButton: false
            });       
            $.post(f.action, f.serialize(), function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                dialog.modal('hide');                    
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

My example controller function code:

```
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            InvoiceTransfer invoiceTransfer = db.InvoiceTransfers.Find(id);
            int pwID = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["PaintballWorkerID"]);
            if (invoiceTransfer.FromID != pwID)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < invoiceTransfer.Invoices.Count; i++)
            {
                db.InvoiceTransfers.Include("Invoices").FirstOrDefault(z => z.InvoiceTransferID == id).Invoices.Remove(invoiceTransfer.Invoices[i]);
            }
            db.InvoiceTransfers.Remove(invoiceTransfer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

It always goes to Index at the end of the function, but browser is not redirecting. As you can see I used `console.log(result)` and in console `result` is always the html code of my Index page.

Comment: Nevermind, I read that I have to use `return Json(Url.Action("Index"));` insted of `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Comment: Why are you using ajax for this in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl to prevent multiple submit, bootbox dialog makes page unreachable until it disappears, so user can't click submit twice or more, even by a mistake